# Redirect to a different tab page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I have a single page index.php with 2 tab button to separated each content. Everytime user click on this tab button they will see different content.

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="javascript:changeTab('dns_soa','dns/dns_soa_edit.php')">DNS Zone</a>
</li>
li class="active"> // current active page
<a href="javascript:changeTab('dns_records','dns/dns_soa_edit.php')">Records</a>
</li> 
</ul>
```

I need to directly redirect to 'dns_records' tab with header redirect after processing form without clicking the tab:

```
header("Location: /dns/dns_soa_edit.php?id=$zone");
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the same file that processes the form, you can use this up the top.

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['zone_id']) ) {
        $zone_id = $_POST['zone_id'];
        header("Location: /dns/dns_soa_edit.php?id={$zone_id}");
    }
?>
```

This assumes that the form has a field with id `zone_id` when using the `POST` method and the target is either left blank in HTML5 specifying the same page, or is set to the name of the same php file. You can just echo `basename(__FILE__)` to get the name of the current php file. In the file `dns_soa_edit.php` (which may be the same file that contains the code above), you would read in `$_GET[$zone_id]` in the same manner and load the details from there.

Comment: I'm sorry I still could not understand you. I know how to redirect with headers but I didn't know how to land the user directly to a active tab page. I still not sure how to redirect user to `('dns_records','dns/dns_soa_edit.php')`

Comment: I fear I misunderstood you as well. Do you refer to tabs as the browser tabs or tabs in your application?

Comment: Tab in my website. I put a demo here: `http://cheapantivirus.me/update.php`. The tab menu didn't work but don't worry because it's works in live site. I just need to redirect user to active tab which is `Records`.

Comment: You can read POST or GET with javascript, and then invoke `changeTab('dns_records','dns/dns_soa_edit.php')` from the script in the header, will that do?

Comment: Correction, you can only access GET variables, but that shouldn't be a problem I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961069/getting-value-get-or-post-variable-using-javascript

Comment: The problem has been solved. I appreciate your help :) Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258126/redirect-with-button