# Redirect with button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a button

```
<button onclick="loadContent('page1.php');" value="Back" type="button"><span>Back</span></button> // I'm not sure how to redirect
```

I also hava a tab page on my website

```
<div class="tabbox_tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:changeTab('soa','page1.php')">SOA</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:changeTab('records','page1.php')">Records</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is how to redirect user to `'records','page1.php'` page when user click button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does calling the changeTab function from your button not do what you want?

Comment: The problem has been solved. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

soa and records can be hashes on page1.php. That is, page1.php#soa and page1.php#records. You can implement these on tabs by wrapping their title in a HTML anchor elements.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea. The problem has been solved. The code is `<button onclick="loadContent('page1.php?next_tab=records');" value="Back" type="button"><span>Back</span></button>` I  don't call `changeTab` but `next_tab` instead. It's from my other use in my website. Thank you.