# issue related to Method POST and GET in HTML

Tags: html, css

i have following HTML

```
<Html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="Page2.html" method="get"/>
    <h1>Hello</h1>

    <input name="fname"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

when i click submit button page is redirect to `Page2.html`  with querystring of `fname`
now how to retrieve the querystring value in `page2.html` page ???

and if i use POST method , how to retrieve post data method ??

Thanks..

Comment: you'd need to use a server side scripting language of some kind, AFAIK there isn't any way to use GET and POST variables in HTML alone. I'd suggest PHP http://php.net

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896854/simple-html-post-without-any-server-scripting-can-be-done-using-js

Answer (score 1):

first, to retrieve a `get` parameter with javascript, use the following function in **Page2.html**:

```
function get_query_param(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

usage:

```
var fname = get_query_param('fname');
```

secondly,

about retrieving `post` parameters, it's impossible with client-side implementation only.

for this, my friend, you will need some **server side** implementation (like php / asp.net / django / etc...).

`post` request are generally used to post some values from the client to the server, for example contact forms.

think about it, `get` is for getting / reading / viewing.

`post` is for writing / storing.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a little scripting(PHP/JS) in your other page. In PHP you can use functions $_GET[] and $_POST[] to obtain GET/POST variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think best way to get parameters from html is using php with variable

$_GET['name'] or $_POST['name'].

If you use post method wou will not be abloe to see data in html, but if you are interested in using just javascript and html you can look at this using  GET method from your form
[here](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/)

Comment: this question is not about PHP

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve value by get or post then you need to do server side codding in J2ee then retrieve values.

For tutorial [J2EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/)

Answer (score -1):

You can not retrieve value in .html page for that you need to set .php or .asp or any other scripting language page.

like below.

```
<Html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="Page2.php" method="get"/>
    <h1>Hello</h1>

    <input type="text" name="fname" value = 'Name_name'/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Page: Page2.php

```
 <?php
    echo $_GET['fname']; // output : Name_name
    ?>
```

Comment: Wrong. `POST` data cannot be accessed on the client side but `GET` data passed in the query string can be accessed with JavaScript.

Comment: please check out method of form its get

Comment: Check yourself first "You can not retrieve value in .html page for that you need to set .php or .asp or any other scripting language page." That's **wrong**.