# How can I process POST data sent from one HTML to another?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, post

I am sending POST form data to Page 2 from Page 1.

**Page_1.html**

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendForm()
        {
            document.forms["form1"].submit();
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="Page_2.html" method="POST" name="form1">

        <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="123">
        <br>
        <input type="button" onClick="sendForm()" id="t2">

    </form>

</body>
```

Now, how can I retrieve the value of the text "t1" in the Page_2.html?

Comment: Are you using any server side languages?

Comment: No, data is being sent from one HTML to another.

Comment: that isn't possible - you have to use GET.

Comment: The answer to this question clarifies it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896854/simple-html-post-without-any-server-scripting-can-be-done-using-js If you are not using a server side language you'll need to use GET and javascript. I don't believe you can read header data without a server side scripting language.