# How to Insert $POST method in Document.Location for Open

Tags: php, post, get

I need to insert the url typed in by User:

```
<input name="endereco" type="text" size="90" maxlength="900" />
```

in:

```
document.location.href = "IN_HERE";
```

Something Similar to:

```
document.location.href = "$ _POST [" address "]";
```

or

```
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=$_POST["endereco"]'>";
```

to open the link previously entered by the User ... how do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961069/getting-value-get-or-post-variable-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var url=document.getElementById("endereco").value;
document.location.href=url;
});
</script>

echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=<?php echo $_POST["endereco"];?>'>";
```

Comment: Thankssss \o great