# Set "option" value of "select" when redirected from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, redirect

I have page A, where I have three anchor.
And page B, where I have select #days with values 30,180,365

So when I click on page A an anchor with href like page?v=30 I should jump to page B, where automatically would be selected option with value=30 on select #days.

Is it possible? I guess easiest would be using jquery or something.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have following PHP code for showing values.

```
<select id="days" name="days">
              <?php foreach($prices as $current_days => $details): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $current_days ?>" <?php selected( $subscription_days, $current_days ); ?>>
                  <?php echo $details['desc']; ?>
                </option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the function written [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) for getting the URL vars, all you need is:

```
$('#days').val($.getUrlVar('v'));
```

[Demo fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nyhag/3/show/light/?v=20)

[Code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyhag/3/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks, it's partially working :)
I have 'value' loaded by PHP (A progammer did that for me, so I can change the values and it's need for payment)
For normal <select> with precoded options - this works :)
How I can make it work, when "value" are called by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the Variable is pretty described here: [Getting value GET OR POST variable using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961069/getting-value-get-or-post-variable-using-javascript)

Now you only need a Javascript that checks if this Value is set, and then simply manipulates the Select Box.
I dont do stuff like that in pure Javascript. jQuery for Example provides verry good functions for this in their API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
function getParameter(paramName) {
  var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
      val, params = searchString.split('&');

  for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    val = params[i].split('=');
    if (val[0] === paramName) {
      return unescape(val[1]);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var v = getParameter('v');

if (v) {
    $('#days').val(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameter from the URL with JavaScript and set the select to the desired value.
An example using jQuery would be this one:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectItem() {
      var i = getParam('v');
      $('#days').val(i);
    }
    function getParam(paramName) {
      return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
      );
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="selectItem()">    
  <select id='days'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="http://server/PageB?value=30">Anchor A</a>
<a href="http://server/PageB?value=180">Anchor B</a>
<a href="http://server/PageB?value=365">Anchor C</a>
```

And from your Page B you have to put this script:

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​

var valueFromUrl = GetQueryStringParams("value");
$("#your-select-id option").each(function()
{
    this.selected = (this.text() == valueFromUrl);
});
```