# How to use javascript to read a datetime input and display it on the next page

Tags: javascript, datetime

So i have a form and as part of it you must enter in a date and a time with a datetime input, like so..

```
<form action="confirmForm.html">
 <p>What date and time suits you? </p>
 <input id="datetime" type="datetime-local" />
</form>
```

and then on the next page, there's just a span tag.

```
<body onload="formConfirm();">
 <span id="confirm"></span>
</body>
```

And my JavaScript..

```
var test = document.getElementById('datetime').value;
document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = test;
```

I expected it to print the datetime to the span tag, but it does nothing. Tried it with alert(test); too but got nothing there either. Pretty confused about this.

Edit: oh and the form has a submit button and all that, forgot to include it here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the form values on the next page you need to pass them using a `get` or `post` method. Use the `method` attribute on the `<form>` element to tell it which one to use.

Normally you'd use `post` to send the form data to be processed on the server (using PHP or another server-side language). That being said, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) may be useful for using `post` with JavaScript.

---

**Edit**:
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961075/1678614) answer you can't access `post` variables in JS on the client side, which makes sense.

But here it is with `get`:
(using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1678614) solution to parse the URI)

**confirmForm.html**

```
<body onload="formConfirm()">
    <span id="confirm"></span>
    <script>
        function formConfirm() {
            var dt = getParameterByName('datetime');
            alert(dt);
            document.querySelector('#confirm').innerHTML = dt;
        }

        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Something important on the form page:
Make sure you give all fields a `name` attribute.

```
<form action="confirmForm.html" method="get">
    <p>What date and time suits you? </p>
    <input id="datetime" type="datetime-local" name='datetime'/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried with method="get" & method="post" but none of them got it to work.