# JavaScript: How to read browser's cache of POST data?

Tags: javascript, caching, post, reload

#### Effort

---

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript), but I still think there has to be a way to do this client side.

#### Case

---

I'm submitting a form that has a few inputs.  When the form is submitted, the primary key of those inputs is shown on a results page along w/ other data and a different form.

The effect I'm trying to do is if the input-pk is modified, I want it to reload the page (think `window.location.reload()`), only I want to update that PK parameter's value with the changed value.

window.location.reload takes one of two values (`true`/`false`), which distinguishes if it should use browser cache or not.  Thus, it seems like it should be accessible, especially since the Firebug::Net plugin shows the param in the HTTP Header.

The form requires 'Post' submissions, which adds a little more complexity.

#### Alternative

---

The other thing I've considered is to store the values in a cookie right before submission, which I can retrieve on the next page and then submit another Post; however I'd like to refrain from exposing the data in Cookies.

Comment: AFAIK, Javascript does not have access to the POST body. Can't think of an API call for that!

Comment: I was hoping that Firefox had some added features and figured I could use some sort of ActiveX in IE. Oh well, cookies it is.  Make your comment an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Javascript does not have access to the POST body. Can't think of an API call for that! If you are using php/.net/ruby, you can encode the POST body as JSON that your JS can use when it's reloaded, can't you?

Comment: I am using Perl, which is the magic duct tape language :) -- that said, issuing a .reload() does not pass changed values, it pulls from the browser cache, which can't be accessed from JavaScript.  My guess is that encoding as JSON would be no different then including a hidden input, which JS can access.