# pass sensitive info into an AngularJS single-page app

Tags: angularjs, post, single-page-application

In addition to its own (TBD) login functionality, I want my AngularJS app to be able to accept a token from another application as a valid login alternative. I don't want that token visible in the URL/GET params, if possible, but I'm not finding any way to process POST params. Currently, the app bootstraps by HTML5. I want to avoid scripting, but PHP and Python are not impossibilities.

Is there a way in Angular to get a POST param?

Comment: Which POST parameter are you talking about?  What is POSTing to what?

Comment: inbound POST from another web app to my AngularJS SPA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get a POST param in a single page app, because you cannot POST to a client like a web browser; you can only POST to a server.

See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

When you make a POST request, your server interprets the variables and returns a resource (like an HTML page) in response.  That page, by default, doesn't have access to any of the headers or data in the request that spawned it.  The only reason that you can access GET params is because JavaScript can inspect the URL of the loaded page, which happens to be where the params are stored.

Some server scripting will be necessary, but it shouldn't be too hard.  A quick and dirty answer would be to use server scripting to inject the POST params into JavaScript code (for example, in PHP)

```
echo "<script>doSpecialLogin(".$_POST['superSecretKey'].");</script>"
```

However, I would also highly recommend that you spend some time making sure that your method is actually secure, and maybe look into technologies like OAuth.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, but worth an ask. Bonus points for OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP request is sent from a client to a server.
You can send data back to the client from the server in two ways: headers and the response body. It works exactly the same for both POST and GET, with the difference that you can also send a request body with POST.

Now let us assume you are using [AngularJS's $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

`$http.get(url)` sends a GET request to the server. You capture the response using `.success(callback)` where callback is called with a parameter representing the response body.

`$http.post(url, requestData)` does exactly the same with `requestData` being the request body sent.

Where

```
function callback(responseBody) {
}
```

Server-side, in PHP, everything that your script outputs is sent back to the client
and the `responseBody` parameter will contain it.

So, with POST, you use the *request body* to send data from client to server and the *response body* to send data from the server back to the client.

This whole "two step" process is a HTTP POST request.