# Insert a variable in javascript POST

Tags: javascript, php, upload

I have a script to upload the photo shoot from the webcam.
The image can properly send it, but I need to send the file savecam.php also a given, it would be the user ID.

```
<?php echo Auth::user()->id ?>
```

While, the part of code is this:

```
    // Upload image to sever 
    document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "camsave.php",
          data: { 
             photo: dataUrl
          }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log('saved');
        });
    });
}, false);
```

I should add, for example,

```
        // Upload image to sever 
        document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "camsave.php",
              data: { 
                 photo: dataUrl,
                 userID:  // <-- HERE ??
              }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log('saved');
            });
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

********* EDIT **********

```
<div class="content">
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <button id="snap">Capture</button>
    <button type="reset" id="new">New</button>
    <button id="upload">Upload</button>
    <div id="userId" display="hidden" value="<?php echo Auth::user()->id ?>"></div>
</div>

<script>
            // Put event listeners into place
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { "video": true },
                image_format= "jpg",
                jpeg_quality= 95,
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                // Littel effects
                $('#video').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#canvas').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#snap').hide();
                $('#new').show();
                $('#upload').show();
            });

            // Capture New Photo
            document.getElementById("new").addEventListener("click", function() {
                $('#video').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#canvas').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#snap').show();
                $('#new').hide();
                $('#upload').hide();
            });

        // Upload image to sever 
        document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 0.95);
            var userId = document.getElementById('userId').getAttribute('value'); //get the value of the the
            $("#uploading").show();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "camsave.php",
              data: { 
                 photo: dataUrl,
                  userId: userId
              }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log('saved');
                $("#uploading").hide();
                $("#uploaded").show();
            });
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

I also tried this, but it seems that it is enough to change the part of javascript and you break something, in fact, no longer shows me the message of acceptance of the webcam.

Comment: Yes where you said here is fine.

Comment: I tried, can you tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: What you have is the correct syntax. Not sure where you stored your userid. And in your php you can pull it using $_POST['userID'] from your random answer below. What you have should function. If properly wrapped in the php file.

Comment: @Geohut That's not true. You can't pull POST data with Javascript. PHP is server-side script. Javascript is client-side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript

Comment: You can... If it's wrapped in a php view. And you place it within a script tag in it. Within the html. That is generated to the client. He isn't pulling post data with javascript he is posting data with JavaScript there is a difference @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: @Geohut, look at the link I provided.

Comment: I read it and that's not what's going on here...

Comment: @Okram92 I updated my answer. Your Javascript method had an error in it

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I posted code below to show you that it is in fact possible to achieve what the OP was showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
post_data = {

      photo: dataUrl,
      userID:  HERE
};
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "camsave.php",
     data: post_data
    }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log('saved');
    });
```

Comment: I tried, but the warning is not enabled to access the webcam, maybe wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this, it should work, but it requires you knowing the user id before you submit the form:

```
<div id="userId" display="hidden" value="<?php echo "your user id" ?>"></div>
```

So you would hide the user id on the page, and then pull it when you send the request.

Then you can do:

```
 document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 0.95);
            var userId = document.getElementById('userId').getAttribute('value');                           

            $("#uploading").show();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "camsave.php",
              data: { 
                 photo: dataUrl,
                  userId: userId
              }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log('saved');
                $("#uploading").hide();
                $("#uploaded").show();
            });
        //you have an extra "})" here, so remove it
        }, false);
```

Here is a JSFIDDLE that shows it working, as much as it can: https://jsfiddle.net/rq0qnc2y/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code below you can clearly see that you can inject that value into the ajax call. you can test the code using http://phpfiddle.org/

```
<?php

        class User
        {
            public $id = 1234;

            public function __get($name){
                return this;
            }
        }

        class Auth
        {
            public static function user(){
                return new User();
            }
        }


        echo Auth::user()->id;




        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head> 
            <body>
                <button id ="upload" width="100" height="100">click me</button>

                <script>
                document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
                //var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                var dataUrl = "weeeh";
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "camsave.php",
                  data: { 
                      photo: dataUrl,
                     userId: <?php echo Auth::user()->id; ?>
                  }
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    console.log('saved');
                });
                });

                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

[image]