# Retrieve POST parameters Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, http-post-vars

How do I retrieve post data in angular.

I have angular app .

```
 My script.js
 ************
 $routeProvider.when('/test1', {
    templateUrl : 'html/test1.html',
controller : 'test1Controller'
}).when('/test2', {
templateUrl : 'html/test2-screen.html',
controller : 'test2Controller'
})
```

Step : 1

---

I have some code that redirects from http://myapp.com/myapp#test1 to another url e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/processdata

Step : 2

---

It would throw back some POST data to my return url,the return url is 
http://myapp.com/myapp#test2 ,that is my angular page.

Referred this on stackoverflow ,
[How to read the post request parameters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

which is perfectly fine, But I need solution for it.

Query :

---

How do I read POST parameters in my page http://myapp.com/myapp#test2

Can the possible solution be as below :

---

Change the return url from angular url to some spring mvc url
e.g.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/return")
public class TestController{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/abc",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getPostParam (ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {
        //Step : 1 retrieve the params here
        Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames(); 
        while(params.hasMoreElements()){
        String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Attribute Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getParameter(paramName));

    }
      //Step 2 : save them in session and redirect it to my angular page 
      response.sendRedirect("/test2");
    }
}
```

Is it a better approach ? Or can someone suggest anything else???

Comment: @NicklasNygren Yes I have mentioned in my question I already read that answer on SO.. I need some solution ,whether it is using spring-mvc /jsp . can you please help ?

Comment: just clarify, do you want to post data while angular routing and getting data from external url?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut  from external url

Comment: I think no way, may be you can send parameters as query string parameters.