# How to read form post data in Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

If the site redirects to my target site with a form post, I want to be able to read the incoming data from the post request using angular 2 typescript.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you need to pass the data from one components to another is it so ?..

Comment: no. My post data is coming from external site. I want to capture it at my end.

Comment: external site means API ?..

Comment: He means a website posts to his website simply put. as my answer states, this requires server handling if you want something like this.

Comment: create a model class and declare corresponding variables, get the data from an external site via services and assign the data to the model's variables, inject the model as a provider in app.module, now you can import that model and access the variables with the external site values, thats it

Comment: Is there a way to extract it in Owin in - ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) ?

Comment: Not an expert here, but any C# handler should be able to access the values, how to share with angular no experience with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's not possible with just angular.
Simply put this answer: [How to read the post request parameters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

However, depending on your server you have options;
When parsing the request you could use a server side language to generate your index.html. e.g. a PHP file.

At this point you could print the post data into a script tag e.g. with PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var somePostData = <?php echo $_POST['some_data']; ?>
</script>
```

Could that be something for you to work with? Of course you'd have to properly escape the data. then it would be accessible like:

window["somePostData"] in your angular code, or you define the type.