# Redirect from external url to my angular 2 application routes with post method and some data

Tags: angular, redirect

I have an angular 2 application & I want to add payment in my app
when user send new payment to my server, I return some data to user and user will send this data with RedirectUrl.

For example: `localhost:4200/result` to another url for example : `x.com`

and from there after payment `x.com` will redirect user to RedirectUrl Parameter sent before with POST method (the result of payment to one of my angualr 2 pages for verifiyng payment).when `x.com` redirect user but I get this message on a page

> Cannot POST /result

what's the matter please help me.

Comment: could you be a bit more clearer ? Do you want to redirect from an external website to your angular website ?

Comment: yes exactly let me send you some link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353067/read-post-form-in-angular-submitted-by-external-websites.
if you understand tell me how can create a little server for my angular 2 application to handle this.notice i have another server that handle my service calls.

Answer (score 1):

As @RomanPuchkovskiy pointed out,you may be out of choices to post the data to your angular application from an external website. You will have to catch your request on the server if you have one or create a server to handle this scenario. One option would be creating a nodejs server that helps you capture the request.**Point the redirect URL to the nodejs server** that you have created and let it process the data.Once you have performed all the needed operations in the nodejs server, make it to **redirect to your specific route** of your angular application.

This is a excellent article from [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) and [malcoded.com](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express). This would help you get some insight into your problem and help you crack the job.