# How to get data from a form in another page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My English is not good enough so I hope you understand what's my problem...

I have a page 'A' with a form. When I click Submit, I want it to open/redirect to a page 'B', and I want to show on page 'B' the data of the form in page 'A'... I want to do this with JavaScript, not with jQuery or so. I've tried with `window.opener` or things like that... Next, the example code is shown.

Page 'A':

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
            <input type="text" name="field1">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="window.open('show.html');">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page 'B':

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var x = opener.document.forms["form1"]["field1"].value;
    document.write(x);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's really important that page 'B' can show data from the form on page 'A'. I can't use PHP or another technology... :/

I hope you understand what I'm asking. Thanks!

**UPDATE

The solution (at least for me) is localStorage, as Sagar Hani indicated. Anyway, thanks to people who answered!

Comment: why `javascript` ?? why not using `post` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the post request parameters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

Comment: You can store the form data object in your local/session storage and access it in next page.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be PHP? With PHP you can also send the info to page B and display to user all the info. In fact, is more user friendly because it's a server side process.

Comment: I know! PHP is super friendly with this stuff, but, I HAVE to use JavaScript, my engineering teacher wants it to be JS...

Comment: Okay, I'm not a javascript expert, but I think the best way is to store the form inputs as a cookie after a submit action in page A and get the cookie in page B. I don't think that javascript can do the stuff without store the info in user browser. But, like I said, I'm not a Javascript expert. 

How to set cookies? It's Easy: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Please thumbs up if I was helpful

Answer (score 1):

- Never you can get **POST** data from client side (using javascript or any other client side language)
- You must use a server side language to get post data (like PHP, nodeJs).
- But you can simply get **GET** data from client side (javascript).

Following is the exact solution that you want.

Page 'A'  (a.html)

```
   <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="b.html" method="get" name="form1" id="form1">
                <input type="text" name="field1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Page 'B'  (b.html)

```
<script>

alert(findGetParameter("field1"))

function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This not works, it return url adress instead input name