# How do I go about displaying the values submitted using the post method In the HTML file which the form was submitted to?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post

I'm using the post method to submit a form to another HTML file I specified with action = " ", but once it redirects me to my second HTML file how can I display the data it received? Using JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the post request parameters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

Comment: Do the HTML documents have the same origin?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a node.js server and read the values that have been posted. HTML itself does not receive data per se, but you can generate HTML server side with what you read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nearly impossible to read POST from client-side [javascript]

Have a look at this : [how to read the post request parameters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `GET` request and parse the query string parameters at requested HTML `document`.

HTML

```
<form action="post.html" method="GET">
  <input name="a" value="1" />
  <input name="file" type="file"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript at HTML document where `<form>` is submitted

```
  const form = document.forms[0];
  form.onsubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // convert `File` object to `data URI`
    if (form.file.files.length) {
      console.log(form.file.files);
      const reader = new FileReader;
      reader.onload = () => {
        form.file.type = "text";
        form.file.value = reader.result;
        form.submit()
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(form.file.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

at HTML document requested by `<form>` `GET` request

```
  // get query string parameters as array of key, value pairs
  // do stuff with form data
  const formData = [...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()];
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/eP8GvUTc4xkPmuc4T8Pu?p=preview