# $.post() html to another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Is it at all possible to post HTML to an HTML file using jquery's post method.

for example:

```
$.post("database.html", "<div>Content</div>")
```

once a button is clicked I want to post to the database file and have this current file load in content from the database file using.

```
$.load("database.html")
```

Does anyone know how I could implement this method properly?

Answer (score 1):

If I rewrite your question a bit: you want to pass data between two html pages. If you only use static html you cannot do that with javascript only. You have to send the data to a server and then use this data in your second html file.

But I think you quite misunderstood what http can or cannot do, I would recommend reading [mozilla explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: Is it possible to do without a server?

Comment: I don't believe so. The javascript context is reloaded each time you access a new HTML page so no data can be exchanged that way.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to pass HTML content in POST** from one HTML page to another. But in order to use or process received the data at the second HTML page, **you'll need a programming language**.

Read the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409029/2408342) to question [*How to read the post request parameters using javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409013/2408342).